# What does $sum:1 mean in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `foo`:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5837199bcabfd020514c0bae"), "x" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583719a1cabfd020514c0baf"), "x" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583719a6cabfd020514c0bb0") }
```

I use this query:

```
db.foo.aggregate({$group:{_id:1, avg:{$avg:"$x"}, sum:{$sum:1}}})
```

Then I get a result:

> ```
> { "_id" : 1, "avg" : 2, "sum" : 3 }
> ```

What does `{$sum:1}` mean in this query?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/):

> When used in the $group stage, $sum has the following syntax and returns the collective sum of all the numeric values that result from applying a specified expression to each document in a group of documents that share the same group by key:
>
> { $sum: < expression >  }

Since in your example the expression is `1`, it will aggregate a value of one for each document in the group, thus yielding the total number of documents per group.

Comment: Expression `1` to a document will return 1, since the expression will apply to each document in the group, so `{$sum: 1}` will return the amount of documents in the group.

Answer (score 7):

Basically it will add up the value of expression for each row. In this case since the number of rows is 3 so it will be 1+1+1 =3 . For more details please check mongodb documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/

For example if the query was:

`db.foo.aggregate({$group:{_id:1, avg:{$avg:"$x"}, sum:{$sum:$x}}})`

then the sum value would be 1+3=4

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what MongoDB version was there 6 years ago or whether it had all these goodies, but it seems to stand to reason that `{$sum:1}` is nothing but a hack for `{$count:{}}`.

In fact, `$sum` here is more expensive than `$count`, as it is being performed as an extra, whereas `$count` is closer to the engine. And even if you don't give much stock to performance, think of why you're even asking: because that is a **less-than-obvious hack**.

My option would be:

```js
db.foo.aggregate({$group:{_id:1, avg:{$avg:"$x"}, sum:{$count:{}}}})
```

I just tried this on Mongo 5.0.14 and it runs fine.

The good old *"Just because you can, doesn't mean you should."* is still a thing, no?