# MongoDB unique values ordered by sum

Tags: mongodb

My collection is as follows:

```
{"orderID" : "30688", "region" : "CO", "customerID" : "11396783", "productID" : "13001"}
{"orderID" : "30688", "region" : "CO", "customerID" : "11396783", "productID" : "8002"}
{"orderID" : "30688", "region" : "CO", "customerID" : "11396783", "productID" : "5001"}
{"orderID" : "89765", "region" : "CA", "customerID" : "54157526", "productID" : "7412"}
{"orderID" : "89765", "region" : "CA", "customerID" : "54157526", "productID" : "5198"}
{"orderID" : "21546", "region" : "KA", "customerID" : "20103585", "productID" : "6851"}
{"orderID" : "21546", "region" : "KA", "customerID" : "20103585", "productID" : "7412"}
{"orderID" : "21546", "region" : "KA", "customerID" : "20103585", "productID" : "6987"}
{"orderID" : "21794", "region" : "NY", "customerID" : "78125522", "productID" : "13001"}
```

I need to count unique orderIDs grouped by customerID in a specific region.
So far I've tried the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
   { $group:
      {
        _id: { region: "$region", customer:"$customerID"}
      }
   },
   { $match: { region: "KA" } },
   {$group: {_id:1, count: {$sum : 1 }}}
] );
```

but it returns an empty result.

Comment: Move the match stage before first group stage and from there either change your groups to 

`{ $group: { _id: { customer:"$customerID", order:"$orderID"} } }` and    `{$group: {_id:"$_id.customerID", count: {$sum : 1 }}}` or { `$group: { _id: :"$customerID", uniqueorders:{$addToSet:"$orderID"} } }` and `{$addFields:{uniqueorders:{$size:"$uniqueorders"}}}`

Answer (score 0):

you should perform the `match` at the beginning of your aggregation, to ensure you are only working with results from that region

you should also change your `$group` to `customer` and `order` as the match has already sorted out things that arent from the desired region

you should then count the number of unique orderID's using `group` by using `{$sum:1}` you can read about how that works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791907/what-does-sum1-mean-in-mongo)

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { $match: { region: "KA" } },
  { $group:
    {
      _id: { order: "$orderID", customer:"$customerID"}
    }
  },
  {$group: {_id:"$_id.customerID", count: {$sum : 1 }}
]);
```